# Angular - lazy loading for non-routed feature modules

Tags: javascript, angular, module, lazy-loading

There is a way in Angular to load **routed** feature modules lazily.
This means if I want to load some module lazily I have to define it in router.

Is there any way to load modules that are **not routed** lazily?
Meaning without defining them in the routes, without reflecting their path in URL, I just want to load them upon specific event in the application.

Answer (score 1):

Angular now has the ability to lazy load code and components using dynamic `import()`.

There's a good example of using `import().then()` to load specific components and then add them to a view:
https://johnpapa.net/angular-9-lazy-loading-components/
However, as the article notes, loading a hierarchy of components is not so easy.

There's also a more detailed look at importing a module here: https://indepth.dev/lazy-loading-angular-modules-with-ivy/